# Using just the first word in an environment variable. batch / cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd, environment-variables

I want to copy a file to a certain location, a Jenkins user will be asked to enter a "project name" in a textfield that will be saved as an environment variable and the batch file should just take the first word of the this environment variable to enter in a directory path.

Now the project name looks something like this:

```
Proj_1 Something Somethingelse
```

Of course this does not work:

```
C:\Testfolder\%Project_Name%\Sub\
```

.. as I just want "Proj_1" to be the folder accessed (it already exists), like this:

```
C:\Testfolder\Proj_1\Sub
Not: C:\Testfolder\Proj_1 Something Somethingelse\Sub\
```

Is there any way to do that in batch? Any help is very appreciated.

Thank you, Jordan.

Comment: You have two options.  Substring the variable by just grabbing the first 6 characters. `%Project_Name:~0,6%`. Or if there will always be a space after the project then use a FOR /F command to get the part of the variable before the space: `FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%G IN ("%Project_Name%") do set "var=%%G"`

Comment: This should be the answer @Squashman

Comment: @Squashman PLEASE use the answer field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demonstrates that @Squashmans second solution in his comment works.

> ```
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
> (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\SBeeson>set "Project_Name=Test Folder Test"
>
> C:\Users\SBeeson>echo %Project_Name%
> Test Folder Test
>
> C:\Users\SBeeson>FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %G IN ("%Project_Name%") do set "folder=%G"
>
> C:\Users\SBeeson>echo %folder%
> Test
> ```

The only difference is the single `%` in `%G` due to it being directly tested in the command environment.  You will need `%%G` for the bat file as he said.

So, your solution is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%G IN ("%Project_Name%") do set "New_Folder=%%G"
```